# Open getter in Kotlin to use it with Mockito - MissingMethodInvocationException

Tags: java, kotlin, mockito, getter

Kotlin can automatically create getters for primary constructor parameters (that's great), and all these getters are final (not open) by default.
I have a class (in Kotlin):

```
open class SongCategory(val id: Long,
                        val type: SongCategoryType,
                        val name: String? = null,
                        var displayName: String? = null,
                        var songs: List<Song>? = null) {
}
```

I wanted to use it in some Mockito test (in Java):

```
SongCategory songCategory = mock(SongCategory.class);
// the line below produces MissingMethodInvocationException
when(songCategory.getDisplayName()).thenReturn("Dupa");
```

This produces `MissingMethodInvocationException` because Mockito needs the mocked class to be open (not final) and the mocked method `getDisplayName()` just has to be open but it's not.

I can't make this getter open or create another overriding getter because it's conflicting with a final getter created automatically for a constructor.

I could move these all parameters to a secondary constructor and create all the properties and getters separately. However if I have to write the same boilerplate code as in Java, so what's the sense of using Kotlin then?

Is there some way to use Mockito with Kotlin-compiled getters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't `open` your class just for the sake of testing. Instead try using the compiler plugin to do this for you. You can read about it here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#all-open-compiler-plugin

Once done, you will be able to use Mockito as any other Java class.

Comment: It's working! But this compiler plugin needs the class to be annotated with some special annotation, so still the class is opened just only for the sake of testing (Instead of 'open' keyword now I have '@Open' annotation beside the class).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I've found that the syntax to open a getter is quite simple (although it's not in the official documentation):

```
open class SongCategory(...
                        open var displayName: String? = null,
                        ...) {
}
```

This opens both the getter and setter for a property.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock) to deal with final method

or alternatively [Javasist](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist) and its `javassist.Modifier`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Unknown, that there are places where you could use the `kotlin-allopen` plugin. But in this case, since all you are trying to do is to mock a Kotlin class (that's not open), you just have to add the `mockito-inline` plugin.

Add the below to your `build.gradle`:

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.0' // use the latest version
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'
```

Comment: Your solution seems to be the best one, but after adding `mockito-inline` dependency I've got an error "This mock maker is not supported on Android". It's strange because it's running on JDK unit test, not on Android. Likely, the problem is with conflicting dependencies.

Comment: Are you using Roboelectric in your project?

Comment: I do use Roboelectric, but even when I threw away Roboelectric, Kotlin and all the libraries, the problem is still the same. It seems like this library 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0' is conflicting with my JDK (Open JDK 1.8.0_152) even on an empty project.